# Python3 tkinter canvas, setting relative width and height

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to set the width of some canvas to the width of master (fullscreen) and the height to 1/5, 3/10 and 1/2 of master. Window is correctly shown, but canvas doesn't appear. I unsuccessfully tried place() instead of pack() with relwidth = 1 and relheight = 0.2.
I just want my three canvas stacked and horizontally filling the window.

```
master = Tk()
master.attributes('-zoomed', True)

w = master.winfo_width()
h = master.winfo_height()
hu = int(h/10)
h1 = hu*2
h2 = hu*3
h3 = hu*5

c1 = Canvas(master, bg='grey', width = w, height = h1)
c1.pack()
c2 = Canvas(master, bg='blue', width = w, height = h2)
c2.pack()
c3 = Canvas(master, bg='red', width = w, height = h3)
c3.pack()
```

Edit: my working code is now:

```
c1 = Canvas(master)
c1.place(rely = 0, relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 1)
c2 = Canvas(master)
c2.place(rely = 0.2, relheight = 0.3, relwidth = 1)
c3 = Canvas(master)
c3.place(rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
```

but I am having a side effect, I can't align at the center a text:

```
c1.create_text(0, 0, text = 'text', fill = 'red', font = ('olivier', 30, 'bold'))
c1.update()
```

that I solved in this unelegnat way:

```
master.update_idletasks()
w = master.winfo_width()
h = master.winfo_height()
ww = int(w/2)
hh = int(h/10)
c1.create_text(ww, hh, text = 'text', fill = 'red')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.place()` geometry manager.

`.place()` has two main parameters which I think you will need.

The first one is `relheight`. True to its name, it sets the height of any widget relative to it's parent widget.

So, if `relheight` was 0.5, then the height would be 0.5(height), or 50% of the parent widgets height.

The same applies to `relwidth`, which works the same way but applies to the width instead.

Read more about `.place()` [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

Also, if you want your code:

```py
master = Tk()
master.attributes('-zoomed', True)

c1 = Canvas(master, bg='grey')
c1.place(x = 0, rely = 0, relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 1)
c2 = Canvas(master, bg='blue')
c2.pack(x = 0, rely = 0.25, relheight = 0.3, relwidth = 1)
c3 = Canvas(master, bg='red')
c3.pack(x = 0, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: `.place()` doesn't work for canvas elements. For that, you need to take the legnth and width of the canvas, and then divide both by two(if you want the middle).

For example:

```py
height = 100
width = 100
c = Canvas(master, bg = "blue", height = height, width = width, highlighthickness = 0)
c.place(x = 0, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 1)
text = c.create_text(height/2, width/2, text = "text")
```

This will place the text `text` in the center of your canvas.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to specify `x` and `rely` as well.

Comment: Should be `x=0` as OP wants the canvases fill the window horizontally.  Also `rely` should be `0`, `0.2` and `0.5` respectively.

Comment: Accepted answer but I am having a side effect: I can't align at center a create_text in canvas... I update my question, "x = 0" removed, it has no effect

Answer (score 2):

At the first time you use `master.winfo_width()` and `master.winfo_height()`,it will be zero.(If you use `print(w,h)`,you will find all of them are zero.)

Just add [`master.update_idletasks()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) before `master.winfo_xxxx`.

All the code could be:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.state('zoomed')

# add here 
master.update_idletasks()
w = master.winfo_width()
h = master.winfo_height()
hu = int(h/10)
h1 = hu*2
h2 = hu*3
h3 = hu*5

c1 = Canvas(master, bg='grey', width = w, height = h1)
c1.pack()
c2 = Canvas(master, bg='blue', width = w, height = h2)
c2.pack()
c3 = Canvas(master, bg='red', width = w, height = h3)
c3.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: working! I accepted previous answer, anyway thank you, now I understand where I was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

`c1.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: TextPositionChange(c1, TextId))`:
On C1(Canvas) Size Change(c1 size will change by window size changing)

`canvas.bbox(TextId)`:
→ x1, y1, x2, y2 of TextId(Item of canvas)

canvas.create_text(text_center_x, text_center_y, options...)

`c1.moveto(TextId, c1.winfo_width()/2-xOffSet, c1.winfo_height()/2-yOffSet)`:
→ canvas.moveto(item, left_top_x, left_top_y)
→ item move to its new_left_top_position

```py
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.state('zoomed')

def TextPositionChange(canvas, TextId):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(TextId)
    xOffSet, yOffSet = (x2-x1)/2, (y2-y1)/2
    canvas.moveto(TextId, canvas.winfo_width()/2-xOffSet, canvas.winfo_height()/2-yOffSet)

c1 = Canvas(master, bg="#111111")
c1.place(rely = 0, relheight = 0.2, relwidth = 1)
c2 = Canvas(master, bg="#222222")
c2.place(rely = 0.2, relheight = 0.3, relwidth = 1)
c3 = Canvas(master, bg="#333333")
c3.place(rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)

TextId = c1.create_text(0, 0, text = "text", fill = "red", font = ("olivier", 30, "bold"))
c1.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: TextPositionChange(c1, TextId))

master.mainloop()
```

You can also see:
https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M60

Hope it can help you.